# How do I to open a project from Team Foundation Server 2010, without project source?

Tags: tfs

How do I to open a project from Team Foundation Server 2010, if that system does not have the project source? By that, I mean: how do I get source from the existing project from Team Foundation Server?

Answer (score 0):

You have to map the TFS path to your local path.  After you have a mapping, then you can "Get Latest" and open the source from your local copy.  Double-clicking on files in Source Control Explorer, will automatically copy the source to your mapped directory structure and open the file.